# Creating a nested dictionary from a CSV file with Python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a a csv file "input.csv" which has the following data.

```
UID,BID,R
U1,B1,4
U1,B2,3
U2,B1,2
```

I want the above to look like the following dictionary; group by the UID as they key and BID and R as a nested dictionary value.

```
{"U1":{"B1":4, "B2": 3}, "U2":{"B1":2}}
```

I have the below code:

```
new_data_dict = defaultdict(str)
with open("input.csv", 'r') as data_file:
    data = csv.DictReader(data_file, delimiter=",")
    headers = next(data)
    for row in data:
        new_data_dict[row["UID"]] += {row["BID"]:int(row["R"])}
```

The above throws an obvious error of

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'dict' objects
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the regular `dict()` you can use `get()` to initialize a new sub-dict and fill it afterwards.

```
import csv

new_data_dict = {}
with open("data.csv", 'r') as data_file:
    data = csv.DictReader(data_file, delimiter=",")
    for row in data:
        item = new_data_dict.get(row["UID"], dict())
        item[row["BID"]] = int(row["R"])

        new_data_dict[row["UID"]] = item

print new_data_dict
```

Also, your call to `next(data)` was superfluous as the headers were automatically detected and stripped from the result.

Answer (score 2):

This is a more efficient version using defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict

new_data_dict = {}
with open("input.csv", 'r') as data_file:
    data_file.next()
    for row in data_file:
        row = row.strip().split(",")
        new_data_dict.setdefault(row[0],{})[row[1]] = int(row[2])
```